# "Having" MySQL clause to use in Grafana

Tags: mysql, grafana

I am using grafana and MySQL to graph some data. I trying to get duplicate rows and show then into a table in my grafana dashboard, I see in my SQL to get duplicate rows is something like this:

```
SELECT email, COUNT(*) Total
FROM clientes
GROUP BY email
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
```

But grafana sintaxys does not allow "having" clause so instead o getting duplicate rows my query results shows all data of the day. Is there any clause similar in grafana to use it?

Comment: Can you please show me how you are displaying the table information in Grafana. I am also trying to do the same thing but every graph has a time-series.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not in grafana  .. but in SQL you could try using a subquery and apply a filter

```
select * from  (
  SELECT email, COUNT(*) Total
  FROM clientes
  GROUP BY email
) t 
where t.total > 1
```

Comment: As you mentioned, aplying a filter and it actually worked. Thank you so much!! @scaisEdge.